# How to delegate key press handling to rlwrap in raw mode terminal with tcl

Tags: terminal, tcl, stty, rlwrap

I use `stty raw -echo` in my tcl terminal program.
What I want is to do some actions for only a few key press events such as <kbd>Tab</kbd>. For the rest of the key press events I want to delegate to rlwrap or other default handling program, such as <kbd>←</kbd> to move cursor to left hand side and insert text in where the cursor is, or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to terminate the program. Is there a way to do it?

Comment: probably not the way you're thinking, since delegating the responsibility across programs makes the terminal connection (and initialization) cumbersome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an option in stty that handles signals for you which is the `isig` option.
Also, `-opost` process "\n" to "\r\n" for you.

```
stty raw -echo isig
```

Another choice is to use explicit `-icanon min 1 time 0` instead of `raw` option.

Answer (score 1):

The latest GitHub [version](https://github.com/hanslub42/rlwrap) of `rlwrap` [has a bindable readline command](https://github.com/hanslub42/rlwrap/issues/44) `rlwrap-direct-keypress` that can be bound (e.g. in your `.inputrc`) to any key you want to pass on directly to your program, bypassing `rlwrap`

All other keys will still work as usual (e.g. moving the cursor) when editing an input line with `readline`

Answer (score 0):

Alas, terminal handling systems don't work in ways that make that easy. *But it isn't impossible.* The simplest mechanism I can think of (indeed, the only one that doesn't make me cringe at the thought) is to use some of the more advanced features of the Expect extension's `interact` command.

In particular, `interact` effectively connects the program `spawn`ed by Expect to the outside world, yet you can also add patterns to allow extended behaviour.

```
package require Expect

spawn /your/program yourarguments...

interact {
    "\t" {
        # Do something special here as we've got a Tab
        send "special special special\r"
    }
}
```

You can use rlwrap on the spawned process:

```
spawn rlwrap /your/program yourarguments...
```

Comment: Thank you. But I didn't install Expect and I want to distribute the program. Not many have Expect installed I guess. Is there a way in tcl to put the program in background when you receive Ctrl+Z?